# Let the vectors $a$ and $b$ form a basis in the linear space $R^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the vectors $a$ and $b$ form a basis in the linear space $R^2$. It is known that $c = a + b, d = a-b$. If the vectors $c$ and $d$ form a basis for the space $R^2$, find the coordinates of the vectors $a$ and $b$ in it, otherwise write down the answer "no".

I think it's not $no$ becouse $c$ and $d$ linearly independat, but I dot know hot to solve it.

Comment: Write down the linear combination $xc+yd = 0$, where $x,y$ are real numbers. Using the fact that $a,b$ form a basis, can you prove that $x=y=0$? If yes, then $c,d$ form a basis, else they do not.

Comment: Since you do think c and d are linearly independent, why do you think they don't form a basis of R2....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}c\\d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&\llap-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b \end{bmatrix}, \quad\text{hence}\quad\begin{bmatrix}a\\b \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&\llap-1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}c\\d \end{bmatrix}.$$